# Regular infinitive or bare infinitive after but?

Tags: grammar

Is there any rule for when to use *to* and when to drop it in expressions that include *but* *(to)* *do*?

> A1-- You have no choice but to study hard.
>
> B1-- You have no choice but study hard.
>
> A2 -- I can't help but keep asking questions.
>
> B2 -- I can't help but to keep asking questions.
>
> A3 -- She could do nothing but give in.
>
> B3 -- She could do nothing but to give in.

I guess all A's are correct. What about the B's? If they are incorrect, is it because of a rule, some logic, or because of idiomatic usage?

Answer (score 2):

Infinitives after *but* meaning *except* are normally used without *to*.

> She could do nothing but give in.

After *cannot(can't) (help) but*+ bare infinitive.

> I can't help but keep asking questions.

We use to-infinitives after *no choice, alternative, option but*

> You have no choice but to study hard.